# why changing input doesn't trigger on change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get change value of input when its values are changed.

http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/694W9/

```
$(function () {
    $('.color-iris').iris();
    $('#color').on('change', function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

I am using color-picker and after the input's value has changed with the new color value, I want to get its value.

But this is not going well.

Please guide me through this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use option `change`

```
$(function () {
    $('.color-iris').iris({
        change: function () {
            console.log(this.value);
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/694W9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Change event would be fired only when that textbox value changes as wel as focus is getting blurred out from the particular text box,so in this context you have to use input

```
$(function () {
    $('.color-iris').iris();
 $('#color').on('input', function () {

 console.log($(this).val());
}) ;
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/694W9/2/)